# Creating a "catchment area" geometry from place points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point

I have data from [Geonames.org](https://www.geonames.org/) on the location of population centres, provided in the format of `Center Name, Latitude and Longitude`.

Only one latitude and longitude point is provided for each population centre.

I would like to create a layer that turns these points into a shapefile of catchment areas around each Population centre, similar to State or Local Government Area set of boundaries.

This could be done e.g. by drawing a boundary between two points at the midpoint between those points.

Is there a way in QGIS to generate these shapefiles automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Run the tool `"Vector > Geometry Tools > Voronoi Polygons..."` on these points, that's all.

---

**References:**

- [wikipedia | Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)
- [Voronoi Diagram on a given polygon using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321945/voronoi-diagram-on-a-given-polygon-using-qgis)
- [Docs » QGIS Training Manual » 18. The QGIS processing guide » 18.14. First analysis example](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/training_manual/processing/john_snow.html?highlight=voronoi%20polygons#first-analysis-example)

Comment: Let @Lucy and she will say enough to her instrument, maybe she will want to split them separate, but this is the review and clarification of the response...

Comment: Voronoi polygons seem to yield the result I wanted, thank you. A more robust way is to overlay with population density data that I have to identify clusters, but I plan to overlay these polygons with that raster file to do so.

Comment: +1, @Taras for quality editing :-)...