# 'Use Layer Extent' not available in v.voronoi

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, voronoi-thiessen

I want to follow the [accepted answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/321948/160545) to the question, "[Voronoi Diagram on a given polygon using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/321945/160545)".

However, in my QGIS (3.16.14-Hannover), in v.voronoi I don't have the option 'Use Layer Extent'. The closest I have is 'Calculate From Layer', but this just produces a bounding box based on the contents of the layer, rather than using the polygon contained in the layer as a hull.

Do I have to upgrade something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `GRASS GIS 7 region extent` to the extent of your polygon layer to get voronoi polygons covering the whole extent of your layer - see the red lines in the screenshot. Then use `Menu Vector / Geoprocessing Tools / Intersection` to clip part of the voronoi polygons outside the initial (blue) polygon.

If you need this more often, create a model for it, then you can do it in one step.

[image]

*Voronoi polygons after intersection processing:*
[image]

Comment: That worked! Unfortunately I don't have sufficient reputation to upvote your answer. Could you perhaps add more detail on how to "create a model" for it, as you suggest?

Comment: To create a model, see: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/processing/modeler_twi.html and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-modeler and ask a new question here if you're stuck.